# How to install application from xamarin to iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, apk

Condition:

1. I am developing a cross-platform application. Xamarin Visual Studio 2019.
2. Publishing for Android - everything is clear, we craft apk and go.

Question:
For example, I want to install this application on iOS purely for my own needs. I do not want to publish in the AppStore, how can I do this? Is there an analog of the apk file for iOS so that I can just share it someway and install it?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use appcenter.ms or Apple's TestFlight to publish ad-hoc builds to test devices, or you can deploy directly to your personal device from Visual Studio

Comment: You will need to build it for iOS, it will create a ,ipa file. Keep in mind you will need to have a mac to build the iOS code on

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [IPA Support in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos) and then you will know how to install application from xamarin to iOS.

In addition to releasing an application for sale through the iTunes App Store, it can be deployed for the following uses:

- Ad Hoc Testing — An iOS application can be deployed to up to 100
  users (identified by specific iOS device UUIDs) for Alpha and Beta
  testing purposes. See our Provisioning an iOS Device for Development
  documentation for detailed information on adding test iOS devices to
  your Apple developer account, and the Ad-Hoc guide, for more
  information on how to distribute in this way.
- In House / Enterprise Deployment — An iOS application can be deployed
  internally, within a company, which requires membership of Apple's
  Developer Enterprise program. More information on In House
  Distribution is detailed in the In House Distribution guide.

Normally, there are two steps:

1. [Creating an IPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos#creating-an-ipa)
2. [Installing an IPA using iTunes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos#installing-an-ipa-using-itunes)